# onclick on the add the new row in the table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am just started with angular.I have a table and a button. on-click on the button a new row like previous one  should be added in the table.i have added stackblitz link below. i am struggling to figure that out.thanks in advance.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcd76w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs6bkq. You need to create an arbitrary array and use its length to define how many rows to display. Notice the `*ngFor` directive placed on the `tr` tag. This is effectively a for loop in your HTML for the number of items in your array. So if you change the length of your array using a function call the number of table rows will update to reflect this.

You can read more about structural directives (like ngFor) here - https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Answer (score 1):

Check this if it helps : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-new-row

I have added some modifications to let inputs have different values.